# How to disable all controls in iphone when activity Indicator is loading?

Tags: objective-c

I am showing activity indicator while getting data from web service and I want to disable all the controls at that time when activity indicator is loading even navigation bar also. I have also set

```
   [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
     [self.navigationController.navigationBar setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
     [searchingBar setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

but it is not working properly..
Any body knows how can I disable all the controls at the time of activityindicator loading;

thanks...

Comment: setUserInteractionEnabled:NO seems to be the best solution, so what exactly is "not working properly" about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use any API, insert a transparent fullscreen UIView behind your activity indicator. It'll "eat" touches.

Comment: It can be applied on UINavigationBar also?

Comment: Depends where you add it. If you do it in your app delegate, and add your transparent UIView as a subview of your root window (UIWindow is a subclass of UIView), it'll cover the whole screen. That's why I told you to use SVProgressHud or at least get some inspiration from there; it's easier to create a new UIWindow and make it an overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use SVProgressHud which you can find on Cocoa Controls or GitHub.

Comment: Why not? it doesn't hurt you know.

Comment: You could always *study* how SVProgressHud is made, it's really well-made and quite easy (basically, it's an overlay UIWindow).